# Simple question on topological groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory

Why is $\{1\}$ closed in a totally disconnected topological group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In every topological space, the connected components are closed (the closure of a connected set is again connected). In a totally disconnected space, the connected components are precisely the singleton sets.